# How to show a sample of the data in BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Let us suppose I have a 1TB dataset in BigQuery, and I want to be able to view the data in a columnar view, limiting to 1000 results. Here are a few of the queries I might use:

```
1. SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT 1000
2. SELECT first_name, last_name FROM mytable LIMIT 1000
3. SELECT last_name, first_name FROM mytable LIMIT 1000
4. SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY first_name LIMIT 1000
```

If I ran these four queries I would be charged ~$20 ($5/tb, pretend `*` = first_name, last_name). This seems like a very high amount to pay to just sample the data -- is there another way to query this data to view a limited view of the data, like the above?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This seems like a very high amount to pay to just sample the data -- is there another way to

If your data dynamic, meaning is updated daily or whatever other way - you can use   [Table Decorators](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/table-decorators)

For example

```sql
SELECT * FROM mytable@-3600000--1800000 LIMIT 1000
```

will query only data inserted within last hour, thus lowering cost a lot!!

Another option is to use [Day partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables) so you can query only specific day worth of data

> Is there a way to export a subset of the data instead of doing a query?

Yes. You can use [Tabledata.list](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tabledata/list) API to list page-by-page data in your original table and insert into new [sampled] table using whatever sampling logic you need. Note: this API is free as it actually doesn't use BigQuery query engine per se, but rather reading from underlying storage!!!  so you can be reasonably wild :o)

Of course you need to implement this in [client](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/libraries) of your choice.

Comment: thanks, in the above case the data wouldn't always be timeseries-based though. Is there a way to export a subset of the data instead of doing a query?

Comment: thanks, also, are you able to add a sort when using the exporter?

Comment: @David542 - no, you can "load" data page by page and do your sorting on client side - again  - this is to prepare your sampled table. so when you present your data that is where then you use order by and whatever else fancy functions in your query.

Comment: The documentation page indicates that the feature has yet to be implemented, though.

Comment: @Dodecaphone - all items in my answer above proved in practice at least during last 2+ years of personal experience with BQ :o)  But shit can happen - so please let me know which exactly feature? can you provide link so i will be able clarify if any confusion?

Comment: Sorry, that was what it said in the link you provided, so I was confused.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you are accessing BQ through the online query interface (https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table . . . ).

Click on the table in the data set.  Go down to where it says "Table Details" in bold letters, beneath the "Run Query" icon.

In the second row below that is an option for "Preview".  This will show you some data and it's free.

Comment: oh, I see. But that wouldn't allow any ordering, correct?

Comment: @David542 . . . True.  The first three queries in your example don't have ordering.

Answer (score 0):

We have a sample table that's generated every day at work which I find extremely useful for many tasks. It's as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE RAND() < 0.01
```

The table is hierarchical, and this sampling is set to reproduce the whole structure; so queries can be tested/replicated in exactly the same form and then swapped over to the big table if needed. The 1% sample applies to the top level of the hierarchy (meaning you don't have to wonder whether you are getting valid results from branches).

For us, there is enough data that sums and ratios are generally very representative. The only kind of data that poses a significant problem is relatively rare events, which means counts of unique elements can't be relied on.

And of course, after the single daily charge for making this table, the billing goes from dollars to cents!